# Loading a file image in a war project

Tags: java, spring, file-io

I´m doing a javaEE application and I´m using spring to inject my ejbs and WAS7, currently I´m running it in a windows environment altough in the end it will run in a unix environment. So I create a java class that acts as my controller for spring and I´m supposed to get some data from a jsp and turn it into an excel. So when I try to get an image from my web-content folder so I can put it into my excel y get file not found.
This is what I´ve tried so far without success:

```
    String path = File.separatorChar + "img" + File.separatorChar +  File.separatorChar + "logoCorporativo.jpg";
    System.out.println(path);

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and

```
        String path = File.separator + "img" + File.separator +  File.separator + "logoCorporativo.jpg";
        System.out.println(path);

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I found that when I typped "http://localhost:9080/AdminMapasWeb/img/logoCorporativo.jpg" into my browser I can see the image.

Does anyone am I getting a FileNotFound Exception???
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
File file = getRequest().getServletContext().getRealPath("/img/logoCorporativo.jpg");
```

getRealPath convert a URL root relative path (using slashes "/") to a File.
If the war does not unpack itself on deployment, getRealPath returns null.

Comment: @Joop `getRequest()` method is not compiled . i get compile time error saying method not found

Comment: @SanKrish he HttpServletRequest parameter if the code is in doGet/doPut/..., normally called `request`

Comment: @JoopEggen Actually my code is in the spring controller. so i tried `request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/img/logoCorporativo.jpg");` but still i get `NoSuchMethodError`

Comment: `request.getRealPath("...")` (from ServletRequest) should then do. Later versions provide a `getServletContext` which makes sense for a non-request function.

Answer (score 1):

your file is packaged inside the *.war archive, so its not a standalone file on the file system (like it is in development)
try using getClass().getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() to get at it

Comment: Best solution if you can put your image in the class path as resource.

Comment: or simple place it inside your *.war archive, something maven will do for you if you put it in /src/main/resources