# Java image storage and use

Tags: java, ant, javax.imageio

I'm currently learning Java and I'm doing a project of html "creation".

The point its than I want to store an image in the jar file and be able to access it in run-time (I'm going to copy the image to a certain folder), but i don't know where to put the image, how to access it from my code, or how to compile it properly. 
I'm currently using ant for the compilation process.

I should give my professor the whole source code and resources, then, he should be able to run `ant proyectX` and it should create the .jar file as an stand-alone app.

I don't want to use a external URL because he is going to test it and maybe, after seeing the code, he would disconnect himself from the internet.
I can't use any external library, just pure java code.

Thank you, and sorry for the bad english.

Comment: What do you mean with "HTML creation"?

Comment: The program should receive one or more text files as arguments and do some tasks whit them, then for each file must create an html file whit info, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a folder in your jar (for example "img") where you will keep all images.

After that you can get the image this way:

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/img/image_1.jpg");
```

Or this way:

```
File file = getRequest().getServletContext().getRealPath("/img/image_1.jpg");
```

[Loading a file image in a war project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043799/loading-a-file-image-in-a-war-project)

[File path to resource in our war/WEB-INF folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder)